# custom signup "signupXhtml"

Tags: scala, lift

Greetings

I'm using the next object to customize the signupXhtml form

The code is the next

object User extends User with MetaMegaProtoUser[User] with ReCaptcha {

............................................
............................................
............................................

```
   override def signupXhtml(user: User) = {
      (<form method="post" action={ S.uri }>
          <table>
            <tr><td colspan="2">{ S.??("sign.up") }</td></tr>
            { localForm(user, false, signupFields) }
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>{ captchaXhtml() }</td></tr>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><user:submit/></td></tr>
          </table>
       </form>)
    }
```

............................................
............................................
............................................
}

and the output in html is the next

```
      <form action="/my/signup" method="post">
          <table>

            <tr><td colspan="2">Sign Up</td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>
            <input id="txtFirstName" name="F443739586660TOG" type="text" maxlength="32" value="" />
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Lastname</td>
            <td>
            <input id="txtLastName" name="F443739586661IYO" type="text" maxlength="32" value="" />
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>email</td>
            <td>
            <input id="txtEmail" name="F443739586662Z43" type="text" maxlength="48" value="" />
            </td>                                                                                                                       
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>passwd</td>
            <td>
                   <span>
                             <input value="*******" type="password" name="F443739586663IFM"  /> Repeat 
                             <input value="*******" type="password" name="F443739586663IFM" />
                   </span>
            </td>
            </tr>

            ............................................... 

          </table>
       </form>
```

I need to customize the email field, as follows:

```
      <input id="txtEmail" name="F443739586662Z43" type="text" maxlength="48" value="" onblur="return my_function();"/>
```

How insert onblur="return my_function();" on txtEmail element ?

I was reviewing:

http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.0/framework/lift-persistence/scaladocs/net/liftweb/mapper/ProtoUser.scala.html#Some%2896%29

and this:

http://www.devcomments.com/Example-custom-registration-at1131253.htm

but did not find anything to help me

anyone have any idea?

please!

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can attach script commands to most of the built in ajax elements in lift by passing the script as an argument when you create an SHTML.text element. Lifts wiring is also something you might want to look into, I know that the [Lift In Action](http://www.manning.com/perrett/) has a chapter that goes into detail about attaching javascript to ajax elements and about wiring as well so that is something that you could look into. You could also post this to the mailing list or take a look through it, it will probably provide the best results

Answer (score 0):

In your User class do something like:

```
override lazy val email = new CustomizedEmailField

protected class CustomizedEmailField(obj: User, size: Int) extends EmailField(obj, size) {
      override def toForm: Box[NodeSeq] =
        Full(SHtml.text("example@email.com", (s) => Alert("hello "+s), ("onblur", "callMyFunc();")))
    }
```

This should override the default email field.